# Proper pronunciation of Kvothe from Kingkiller Chronicles?

Tags: the-kingkiller-chronicle, pronunciation

I have come into a debate with some friends of mine about how to properly pronounce the name of Kvothe, the protagonist from Patrick Rothfuss’ *Kingkiller Chronicles*.

I seem to recall — but cannot find — Kvothe saying that his name is pronounced like “Quothe”. Some of my friends insist that both the *k* and *v* sound are explicitly sounded out, the way you do at the start of the verb [*kvetch*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kvetch).

What’s the right way to pronounce *Kvothe*, and why?

Comment: I actually thought he said his name was _not_ pronounced like 'quothe'.

Comment: Almost like Quothe, as Micah says below

Comment: It's in chapter 7 of the first book: "My name is Kvothe, pronounced nearly the same as 'Quothe.'"

Comment: Kvothe the Raven: Nevermore.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Patrick Rothfuss, the author of the *Kingkiller Chronicles,* [says:](http://blog.patrickrothfuss.com/2008/02/ask-author-4-how-do-i-pronounce-kvothes/)

> **Ask the Author #4: How Do I Pronounce Kvothe’s name?**
>
> The initial “kv” sound in “Kvothe” doesn’t crop up in standard English that often. But it does appear in the Yiddish term “kvetch.”
>
> The “o” is the same as in “roll” or “hole.”
>
> The “e” is silent.
>
> If you’ve been pronouncing it wrong, don’t sweat it. You’re not alone.
>
> ...
>
> I put that bit in right at the beginning of his story. “My name is Kvothe, pronounced nearly the same as ‘Quothe.’”
>
> Kv + Quothe = Kvothe. Simple.

Comment: What is Quothe from? Is that a character in an sf work or what? Are we supposed to know how Quothe is pronounced? If the e is silent, I guess it would be pronounced like the English word quoth, as in "quoth the raven"? Or is Quothe pronounced with voiced th as in loathe?

Comment: If the 'e' is silent then it's "Quoth", as in _Quoth the Raven “Nevermore.”_ Making Kvothe "Ka-Voth" with the "oth" sounding like the end of _quoth_ and **not** like heavily mascaraed "goth".

Comment: @BinaryWorrier No, if the e is silent, it is most likely meant to rhyme with _loathe_ (where the e is also silent). A silent e at the end of a word in English usually indicates that the preceding syllable is long, but also that the preceding consonant (if a fricative and orthographically ambiguous, like ⟨th⟩, which can represent both /θ/ and /ð/ or ⟨s⟩, which represents both /s/ and /z/) is voiced. This is because fricatives were voiced intervocalically in Old/Middle English and stayed that way even when the final e disappeared. So most likely /kvəʊð/, not /kvəʊθ/. Definitely not /kvɔθ/, no.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best explanation actually comes from **The Wise Man's Fear, Page 313**

> "Ka-voth-ee." He read slowly, then turned the envelope toward me so I could see the front.
>
> (Front of letter)
>
> It was Denna's handwriting. "It's Kvothe, actually," I said absentmindedly. "The e is silent."

Based on Kvothe's corrections I think it's safe to presume the proper pronunciation would be Ka-voth with the oth sounding like Quoth.

Comment: I think the "a" between the k and v is also a mispronunciation that is only used because that consonant cluster is not familiar to English speakers. Micah's quote from the author seems to indicate that the intended pronunciation is monosyllabic.